# Any option in C++ to set default variable type to int

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-options

Is there any option **to omit variable type** or **to set variable type to** `int` in c++ code that to be compiled with g++ compiler in linux.

```
    const bufLen = 2000;
```

Compilation went fine in solaris (as I am  doing porting from solaris to linux).

One more thing ,**I dont have control over the file** as it is generated by some parser (provided by some third party in the form of binary)

Since I cant change the c++ file(as it is generated everytime before compilation) , I need some option (of g++) so I can include during compilation to suppress/resolve the error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `bufLen` with no type
```

---

**EDIT :**

**INFO** : options currently I am using `-c -fPIC -Wno-deprecated -m32 -O2 -ffriend-injection -g`

Is anyone of the options causing me trouble (or affecting other) ?

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's a C++ (and not a C) file? C89 allowed `int` to be omitted.

Comment: Can you just compile it as C code? In other words use the C compiler and not the C++ compiler.

Comment: @sashang : It is c++ file not c file . I just mentioned one line which is giving me trouble from 10,000 line parser-generated C++ file

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the question, but as an info: `const auto bufLen = 2000;` and compile with `g++ -std=c++0x`.

Comment: @Makesh Can you complain to whoever is responsible for generating this crap? It’s probably very old software so the chances may be slim, but that’s the best course of action …

Comment: it's not that hard to 'preprocess' the file yourself and do a regex find/replace so const x = y; becomes const int x = y;

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I wished the same but it too compilcated that file is generated by more than 3 parsers (all binaries) and I dont know which parser is responsible for that segment of code :(

Comment: have you tried -fms-extensions ?

Comment: Implicit `int` is a disaster. I had to work some time with ancient compiler which supported it and got furious every time a constructor with misspelled name got compiled happily as a function returning int.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your efforts on giving me suggestions

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: I agree, implicit int is one of the stupidest ideas that were ever part of C, thank god it's gone for good...

Comment: @MFH: Arguably, automatic function prototyping is even stupider.

Comment: good that it worked! was just a lucky guess on my part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to AndersK who gave me a solution (through comments [below my question])

I tried compiling using `-fms-extensions` with g++ which resolved my problem

Reference : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

PS : *For visibility sake , I added the answer in answer section . Credits go to person who actually answered :)*

Comment: Do realize the irony of using -fms-extensions to get your code to compile? -fms-extensions was added to gcc to enable support for Microsoft specific extensions to the language (http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/1999-08n/msg00363.html). I seriously doubt that the original code you're porting from Solaris to Linux has anything related to Microsoft in it. My guess is that real issue is the code generator is generating C code, and your problem is that you're compiling C code with the C++ compiler. Just change the compiler options to tell gcc to use the C compiler, as other people have noted.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-ansi` or `-std=c89`. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: That won’t work if the file does indeed contain C++ (as opposed to pure C) code.

Comment: In that case its not iso comform c++ code as stated by the error message

Comment: @Paranaix : this is how I am compiling : /usr/bin/g++ xyz.cc -c -fPIC  -Wno-deprecated -m32 -O2 -ffriend-injection -g -I/some_inc_dirs -o xyz.o  ... Will it help ??